# Populating field based on value of another field using Boolean OR

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, field-calculator, python-parser

I am trying to enter values for a new column, `FloodZone`, based on another column's (`NEW_ZONE`) values. I am doing this in `ArcGIS Pro 3.1` using the `Calculate Field Tool` via `Python`. However, I am getting a syntax error.

How can I fix the syntax?

I used this guide to write the syntax:

[Use IF statements in the Calculator Field tool in ArcGIS Pro](https://support.esri.com/en-us/knowledge-base/how-to-use-if-statements-in-the-calculator-field-tool-i-000027512)

This is how I am defining the new values:

```
NEW_ZONE FloodZone
AE       High Risk Area
AH       High Risk Area
AO       High Risk Area
VE       High Risk - Costal Area
D        Undetermined Risk Area
X        Moderate to Low Risk Area
```

Syntax:

```
FloodZone = reclass(!NEW_ZONE!)

def reclass(NEW_ZONE):
    if(NEW_ZONE == "AE" or NEW_ZONE == "AH" or NEW_ZONE == "AO":
        return "High Risk Area"
    elif(NEW_ZONE == "VE"):
        return "High Risk - Coastal Area"
    elif(NEW_ZONE == "D"):
        return "Undetermined Risk Area"
    else:
        return "Moderate to Low Risk Area"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the closing parentheses `)` at the end of line `if(NEW_ZONE == "AE" or NEW_ZONE == "AH" or NEW_ZONE == "AO":`